# SQL Server 2008 - Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, data-import

I am trying to copy all the tables and views from a database on SQL Server 2005 to a database on SQL Server 2008 using the Import data wizard, but after running for some time it just copied 230 tables from 570 tables and views and gave the following warning.

> Warning 0x80019002: Data Flow Task 46: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

What is the best possible fix for this? How can I change the max error count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not change the error count. That is just masking the problem. FInd out why you are getting errors and fix that.

Comment: If @Pinu wants to get rid of the errors, choosing a tool other than SSIS would be a good start.

Comment: Well I usuually log errors using logging (this doesn't identify specific records more the step that has failed) or send bad records to an error logging table in the dataflow itself using a conditional split.