# SQL Server Backup Jobs Failing. The error seems to be related to MaximumErrorCount, but I am not sure how to fix value or if changing it will resolve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

My Backup jobs are failing with following error when check it's history. I have already checked this link regarding maximumerrorcount value.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250648/sql-server-2008-change-the-maximumerrorcount-or-fix-the-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803547/biztalk-server-backup-job-on-sql-server-2000-fails)

At this point I'm not sure what to do if maximumerrorcount is only masking the actual problem.

Log     Job History (DB_TaxExemption_BKP.Subplan_1)

> Step ID       1 Server        INHOUSE-DB Job Name     DB_TaxExemption_BKP.Subplan_1
> Step Name     Subplan_1 Duration      00:00:00 Sql Severity   0 Sql Message
> ID    0 Operator Emailed   Operator Net sent   Operator Paged  Retries
> Attempted 0 Message Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE.
> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version
> 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:12:00 PM  Error: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.47
> Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: {4D6AAF94-D3FC-4873-9F66-E35E323A6BEE}
> Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "Local
> server connection". Connection may not be configured correctly or you
> may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error
> Warning: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.47     Code: 0x80019002     Source:
> OnPreExecute      Description: SSIS Warning Code
> DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but
> the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1);
> resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches
> the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the
> MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  Error: 2022-03-30
> 22:12:00.48     Code: 0xC0024104     Source: Back Up Database (Full)
> Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code
> 0x80131904 (Login failed for user 'backupuser'.). The Execute method
> must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.  End
> Error  ## Heading ##Error: 2022-03-30 22:12:00.48     Code: 0xC0024104
> Source: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}      Description: The
> Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131904 (Login
> failed for user 'backupuser'.). The Execute method must succeed, and
> indicate the result using an "out" parameter.  End Error  Warning:
> 2022-03-30 22:12:00.48     Code: 0x80019002     Source: OnPostExecute
> Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The
> Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2)
> reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
> when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
> MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
> End Warning  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
> Started:  10:12:00 PM  Finished: 10:12:00 PM  Elapsed:  0.219 seconds.
> The package execution failed.  The step failed

I know for sure that the user for this backup job is sysadmin and it is not locked out all rights are grated. And this is production so I cannot take many risks. What am I missing ?

Comment: The error is `Failed to acquire connection "Local server connection"`

Comment: But other jobs from same user with same permissions are working.